# Unity 3D: Как можно сделать так чтобы при движении мыши по оси Y, объект изменил свою позицию по оси Z. (движение объекта мышкой.)

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-android, position

На данный момент объект изменяет свою позицию только по X и Y, хочу сделать так чтобы вместо движении по Y, объект двигался по Z.

```
public class ClickDetector : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject player;
    private Rigidbody rbPlayer;
    private Vector3 offset;
    private Vector3 newPos;

    void Start()
    {
        rbPlayer = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        offset = rbPlayer.position - Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.z));  
    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        newPos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
        rbPlayer.position = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(newPos) + offset;
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы двигать по Y, двигай по Z. У тебя в самом вопросе ответ.

Comment: ты прочитал код?)

Comment: прочти код еще раз пожалуйста, если точно поймешь о чем я говорю, попробуй на примере мне показать как это можно сделать :)

Comment: Ну в этом случае, я думаю лучше не ответить на вопрос в котором не совсем разобрался ))

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю что ты там пытаешься делать, когда вычисляешь оффсет, наверное костыль какой-то, чтобы объект не улетал в нулевые координаты. Все гораздо проще.

```
public class Movement: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 10f;

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        var x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        var y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        var position = transform.position;

        position.x += x * _speed * Time.deltaTime;
        position.z += y * _speed * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.position = position;
    }

}
```

Смещение мыши прибавляешь к позиции. Всё. Не нужен никакой оффсет.

Зачем тебе Rigidbody игрока тоже непонятно, если ты просто его позицию меняешь. Если уж берешь Rigidbody, то используй метод MovePosition, чтобы телепортировать, позицию изменять можно и у обычного трансформа игрока.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Изменение позиции через Rigidbody требует гораздо меньше ресурсов чем через колайдеры (MovePosition или похожие методы которые работают с колайдерамы), плюс мне по любому нужна физика для этого объекта, вот поэтому я и использую Rigidbody.position, зачем мне тратить больше ресурсов?)). В offset хранится расстояние между координатам мышки и координатам объекта, который во время перемещения мышки прибавляется к новым координатам объекта...таким образом не в зависимости от координата курсора мышки, объект остается в своем позиции (между ними всегда остается расстояние).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136281/discussion-on-answer-by-kotlk-unity-3d-------).